# How can Belady's anamoly be avoided?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, page-replacement

When we increase the number of frames to the process then the number of page fault should decrease but instead the page fault increase sometimes (Belady's anamoly). How this can be avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Belady's anomaly is prevalent with a FIFO eviction policy. Every eviction policy will have a pattern that will "break" it. However, there are a few eviction policies that can avoid Belady's.

1. Random eviction
2. LRU (Least Recently Used)

[Here is more information](http://ranger.uta.edu/~weems/NOTES5314/HW/hw3.3.pdf)

Comment: can you please explain random eviction??

Comment: Random eviction is straightforward. Whenever we need to evict, we select a random page to evict (via a random number generator). No internal structures or metadata needed like FIFO and LRU.